# How to define multipurpose (i32/f32) register in an LLVM backend?

Tags: llvm

I'd like to define a register as a multipurpose float and integer register on an LLVM back-end. Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could see how it is implemented in LLVM backend for any
architecture you are familiar with. For example, ARM has 32
D-registers (D0..D31) which can hold either double float or vector
values. In this case `RegisterClass` definition is quite
straightforward:

```
// Scalar double precision floating point / generic 64-bit vector register class.
def DPR : RegisterClass<"ARM", [f64, v8i8, v4i16, v2i32, v1i64, v2f32], 64,
                        (sequence "D%u", 0, 31)> {
  // Allocate non-VFP2 registers D16-D31 first.
  let AltOrders = [(rotl DPR, 16)];
  let AltOrderSelect = [{ return 1; }];
}
```